# Windows Service COM error?

Tags: com, windows-services

I've written a Windows service in C# that runs fine on XP, but when I install it on server 2008 I get the following error:

```
Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID 
{20A80B2B-6D69-40B7-A66A-D63C60B4878C} failed due to the following error: 80040154.
```

Anyone know what this is about?

Answer (score 1):

80040154 is ERROR_CLASS_NOTREGISTERED, so you should start by debugging your installer and verifying that it is writing the correct values into the registry.

Answer (score 1):

Googling the class id brings up "tidyatl.dll" - part of a DICOM viewer, right? You will need that application installed on the 2008 server you are running the service on. The C# service has a dependency on it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was I had a third party DLL that had to be registered in Windows.  Errr...